# Create dataframe based on index from list with different size

Tags: python, pandas

What I'm trying to do is to create a dataframe based on a list as index and with a dataframe already determined:

df1:

```
index   flag   value
3       1      99
5       1      98
7       1      97
```

index list:

```
all_index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

then get this output:

df2:

```
index   flag
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       1
4       NaN
5       1
6       NaN
7       1
8       NaN
```

I was trying to do it in this way but doesn't works:

```
df2 = df1.loc[all_index]['flag']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need `reindex`:

```
df2 = df1.reindex(all_index)["flag"]
```

Answer (score 1):

use `reindex`

```
df.set_index('index').reindex(all_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the exact layout (as a dataframe instead of a series), you can use [`.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) in this way:

```
df2 = df1.reindex(all_index)['flag'].to_frame()
```

Or

```
df2 = df1.reindex(all_index)[['flag']]
```

Result:

```
print(df2)

   flag
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   1.0
4   NaN
5   1.0
6   NaN
7   1.0
8   NaN
9   NaN
```